# Is it possible to recover images from Kodi's pictures using a remote controller via a JSON-RPC Request?

Tags: json, angularjs, json-rpc, kodi

I'm trying to recover the pictures from Kodi, as it is possible with Musics and Movies via a Json-RPC request. However, while a built-in request is available to recover Movies, Musics and TVShows, I don't find any request that could possibly recover images from the Library or a Folder.

Answer (score -1):

http://192.168.2.4/jsonrpc?request={%22jsonrpc%22:%20%222.0%22,%20%22method%22:%20%22Player.GetItem%22,%20%22params%22:%20{%20%22properties%22:%20[%22thumbnail%22],%20%22playerid%22:%201%20},%20%22id%22:%20%22VideoGetItem%22}

wil get you this result.

{"id":"VideoGetItem","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"item":{"id":44,"label":"Promenade","thumbnail":"image://F%3a%5cMovies%5cPruimenbloesem%5cfolder.jpg/","type":"movie"}}}